# java unit test always give negative result although the array is the same

Tags: java, junit, junit4, hamcrest

```
assertEquals(expected, actual);
assertArrayEquals(result.toArray(), expected.toArray());
assertThat(result, hasItems(
    Transfer("888881", "111111", 3
}
```

All the above gives:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.ArrayList<[Transfer(from=888881, to=111111, amount=3)]> but was: java.util.ArrayList<[Transfer(from=888881, to=111111, amount=3)]>
```

Doesn't the arrays show in the error are the same?

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you implement `equals` in `Transfer` properly?

Comment: @Sweeper Solve it after implement equals.

Comment: you should never implement those methods for testing purposes.